# toggle css class for active link

Tags: html, css

I have 5 links on page, when i click on each link it will change the color but as soon as ma=ove my cursor and place on other area of page, the focus on active link gets disappear. so I am not able to show the current link state. please tell me how to fix

Comment: http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css

Comment: http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/

Comment: http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol9/css_no1.htm

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/roll11.htm

Comment: <tr><td ><a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic2</a><td></tr>
<tr><td ><a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic3</a><td></tr>
<tr><td ><a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic4</a><td></tr>

and css is:
.linkbold{
 color:#0066FF;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:11px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold !important;
}

Comment: Edit your question and Place the code there... It looks like junk in comments section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Html**

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic2</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic3</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="#" class="linkbold">Basic4</a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

**Css**

```
.linkbold{ color:#0066FF; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold !important; }
.active { color: red; } // define any color for active class

// you can use css shorthand for font property
.linkbold { font: bold 11px Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#0066FF; }
```

If you want to know more about [css shorthand](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-css-shorthand/)

​**Jquery**

```
$('a.linkbold').on('click', function(){
    $('a.linkbold').removeClass('active'); // remove any active class
    $(this).addClass('active'); // and then add active class for clicked element.
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/TkPBV/2/)

Comment: can it be doen with javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: as the title says "[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) is a new kind of JavaScript Library."

Comment: yes, but in my application i am using extjs where I cant insert jquery inside ne js file.

Comment: there is a getting started page about it http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Using_Ext_With_jQuery

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link {color:blue;}
        a:visited {color:red;}
        a:hover {color:green;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">first</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#">second</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have 5 links, it means when i click on next link the previous link should gets to its original state.